# Appium Send keys() function sending Chinese characters as part of English strings

Tags: java, api, selenium, appium

while using appium `send keys()` function to send the name in text field,in addition to name some random chinese characters appear in the text field.

we used in  capability

```
capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", "true");
```

even thought we could not solve the error

```
public ProfilePage click_On_Edit_Profile_Icon(String Name, String Email,String Alt_Mobile )throws Exception {
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,'etFlat')"].click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,'etFlat')"].sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a", Keys.DELETE),Name);
Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

end result is showing this way
`"漢字name"`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these capabilities, one or the another or both, try different combinations.

```
capabilities.setCapability(“locale”, “en_US”);
capabilities.setCapability(“language”, “en”);
```

Also try removing your capability...

```
capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", "true");
```